# How to use Mobx for List object in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobx

I want to change the status of checkbox via use Mobx, after the click the value have changed but not update on UI, Observer don't see change action that it is rebuilding this Widget
In file Mobx:

```
  @observable
  List<bool> statusCheckbox = List<bool>();

  @computed
  List<bool> get getStatusCheckBox {
  return statusCheckbox;
 }

 @action
 changeStatusItem(bool val, int index) {
 statusCheckbox[index] = val;
 }
```

In file contain Widget:

```
Observer(
                 name: 'ListHomePage',
                 builder: (BuildContext context) {
                 return  child: GridView.builder(
                              gridDelegate:
                                  new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                crossAxisCount: 3,
                                childAspectRatio: (itemWidth  / itemHeight),
                              ),
                              itemCount:
                              _userManagementStore.userAPI.users.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                UserManagement user =
                                _userManagementStore.getUser(index: index);
                                return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredGrid(
                                  position: index,
                                  duration:
                                      const Duration(milliseconds: 375),
                                  columnCount: 2,
                                  child: Container(
                                    child: ScaleAnimation(
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                        child: Stack(
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                             Align(
                                              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                              child: Checkbox(
                                                value: _userManagementStore.getStatusCheckBox[index],
                                                onChanged: (bool val) {

                             _userManagementStore.changeStatusItem(val, index);

                                                },
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                  },
                )
```

I can't find the root cause of the issue

Comment: Why do you need @computed property? There is no computation at all in it, just returning an observable value. What is the point of this? Anyways, is it possible to provide some kind of  code sandbox in able to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As said Antoan Elenkov, you should remove the `@computed` property.
But you main problem is that you should not using a `List` but an `ObservalbleList`, it works like a `List`.
So, you have to replace

```
  List<bool> statusCheckbox = List<bool>();
```

by

```
  @observable
  ObservableList<bool> statusCheckbox = ObservableList();
```